# Let A be a $3×3$ upper triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are $1, 2,−3$. How to express $A^{−1}$ as a linear combination of $I,A$ and $A^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a $3×3$ upper triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are $1, 2$
and $−3$. Express $A^{−1}$ as a linear combination of $I,A$ and $A^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Recall by the Cayley–Hamilton Theorem, every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of $A$ is $(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)$ i.e. $x^3-7x+6.$

Due to the *Cayley-Hamilton theorem,* $A^3-7A+6I=0$

$\\\implies A^{-1}(A^3-7A+6I)=0,\text{ the inverse exists since none of the eigenvalues is zero}\\\implies A^2-7I+6A^{-1}=0\\\implies A^{-1}=\frac{1}{6}(7I-A^2).$